# which.max and assign colnames value to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the max value and assign the colnames back to the data frame. I tried to loop it. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
new<-data.frame(id=seq(1:5),att1=rnorm(5,1),att2=rnorm(5,1),att3=rnorm(5,1))
for (i in 1:nrow(new))
new$type<-names(which.max(new[i,2:4]))

id       att1       att2      att3 type
1 -1.1735401  0.1269600 0.6178781 att3
2  1.9650696 -0.2129732 0.5030030 att3
3 -0.0901813  4.3937726 1.1886939 att3
4  0.1719326  1.9478824 2.2497336 att3
5  2.1359702  2.3347643 2.6607773 att3
```

Comment: I think you should use `.. new$type[i] <- ..`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `apply`;

```
new$type <- names(new)[apply(new[-1], 1, which.max) + 1]

  id        att1      att2       att3 type
1  1  1.77432474 0.3306480  0.9693518 att1
2  2 -0.00585121 0.2115700  0.6579220 att3
3  3  0.23611749 0.7180739  1.9325201 att3
4  4  0.43156117 0.9980831 -1.2525760 att2
5  5  2.10921757 1.3001635  0.4259629 att1
```

Comment: if there are two columns which have same value, it would only get one result.

Comment: `new$type<-apply(new[,2:5],1,function(x) names(which(x==max(x))))` found the solution after i try with `apply`. tahnks

Answer (score 2):

```
names(new)[2:4][max.col(new[, 2:4])]
```

As a general rule, don't use `apply` with data frames. It will turn the input df into a matrix, which, if you have any character or factor columns, will result in a character matrix.

Comment: Yes, `apply`, will transform the data frame into a matrix. But the same applies to `max.col`. Have a look at the code, particularly the following line: `m <- as.matrix(m)`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I did say "as a general rule". In this case all the necessary columns are numeric so it's safe to use `apply` (after you do proper subsetting). But often you want to do a row-wise operation on a data frame that involves both numeric and character/factor columns, and `apply` won't help then.

Comment: hmmm.. what if I want to return more than one names? if there are two columns share same max?